# JIS キーボード配列の mac で、vscode の Terminal を新規に開くショートカット [^⇧`] を利用したい

Tags: vscode

JIS キーボードの mac で vscode を利用しています。 Terminal 画面を一つ開いている状態から、別の Terminal 画面を追加で開く操作、 New Terminal を、キーボードショートカットで行いたいです。これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

というのも、この New Terminal のアクションは、キーボードショートカット自体は、<kbd>[^⇧`]</kbd>にバインドされている様子です。（メニューから Terminal -> New Terminal をみに行くことで確認できる）

しかし、手元で実際このコマンドを実行しようと、 <kbd>Shift + Control + @</kbd>を入力してみると、これは<kbd>[^⇧@]</kbd>である、"Toggle Integrated Terminal" アクションに紐付けされている様子です。（自分の手元のキーボードでは、バッククォートは<kbd>@</kbd>のシフト面に配置されており、それを入力する方法が、あるのかそもそも、と思っています。）

#### 質問

- JIS キーボードの Mac において、  New Terminal をキーボードショートカットから実行したいです。これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか？

Comment: shift+cmd+p でコマンドパレットを開き。key と打って表示される Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts を選択してキーバインド一覧から、該当ショートカットを鉛筆アイコンをクリックで、ショートカットそのものを変更してしまうのも手かと。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私の知る限り、2018年11月現在 VS Code でこの問題を根本から解決する方法は無いはずです。たとえば VS Code Wiki の ["Keybinding Issues"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues) には以下のように書かれています。

> VS Code does not ship with default keybindings optimized per keyboard layout. For example, <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> cannot be mapped by VS Code automatically to a scan code on the Ukrainian keyboard layout because no modifier + scan code combination produces <kbd>`</kbd> on the Ukrainian keyboard layout. You can upvote in [issue #1240](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1240).

とりあえずの回避法として使えるのは、キーバインドを変更することです。メニューの「ファイル」→「基本設定」→「キーボードショートカット」から出てくるキーバインド一覧から目的のものを探し、競合しないように書き換えてしまえばよいです。

一応 VS Code ではキーボードレイアウトに応じて良い感じにデフォルトのキーバインドを解釈する[仕組みがある](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-layouts)のですが、今回の例ではそもそも <kbd>`</kbd> と <kbd>Shift+@</kbd> が同じ操作を指すため上手くいきません。このため、現状手動で解決する形になっています。